# Training dataset from analytical solution

Tags: machine-learning, probability, eigenvalues, noise

I am currently redesigning an inverse problem on an experimental technique, but I am having doubts about how to create a training dataset. Here is the problem I am trying to solve:

I have already created a model in order to solve the forward problem, such that if I input $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$, the model solves a generalized eigenvalue problem and returns the expected output $y_1,y_2,..,y_m$.

Thus, what I am trying to do is to generate random $(\vec{x},\vec{y})$ pairs in order to create a training data set that will allow me to solve the inverse problem. Considering this, I am confused as if the random $(\vec{x},\vec{y})$ pairs should be considered as synthetic data (since they come from the actual analytical solution). If so, should I generate the training data by following a probability distribution and adding noise?